# Number of loops in recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I would like to count the number of positive integers/elements in the list. This returns the elements with positive values, how can I count the elements? would like to construct something like count(array(...)).

I would like to see a version with *i++* and *foldl*. That would be very helpful.

```
countPositivesRec :: [Int] -> [Int]
countPositivesRec [] = []
countPositivesRec (x:xs) | x >= 0 = x : tl
                         | otherwise = tl
                           where tl = countPositivesRec xs
```

Comment: Err, `length . countPositivesRec` ?

Comment: `i++` is fundamentally not Haskell; that's the postincrement operator in C, implying both defined computation order and mutable variables. The closest equivalent might be `succ`, which increments, but the new value is a distinct value.

Comment: `filter (>=0)` would avoid recursion and use library functions.

Comment: Where do you want the count to appear? Do you want a function with a type signature like `[Int] -> (Int, [Int])`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: follow the same recursion scheme as before, but return an int at every step.

```
countPositivesRec :: [Int] -> Int
                              ---
countPositivesRec [] = 0 -- no positives in the empty list
countPositivesRec (x:xs) | x >= 0    = ??
                         | otherwise = ??
                          where tl = countPositivesRec xs
```

One you solve this, it can be rewritten using `foldr`, if you want.

If you really want to use `foldl` instead, I would suggest you start by defining a function `f` such that

```
f (f (f 0 x0) x1) x2
```

evaluates to the number of positives in `x0,x1,x2`. Then you can use `foldl f 0 inputList`

Answer (score 1):

The function you've written is `filter (>=0)`. As Paul pointed out, the only step remaining is to count and `length` does that. We can transform the function step by step:

```
countPositivesRec :: [Int] -> [Int]
countPositivesRec [] = []
countPositivesRec (x:xs) | x >= 0 = x : tl
                         | otherwise = tl
                           where tl = countPositivesRec xs
```

Observe that `xs` is only used in the transformed form `tl`. That's what makes this a right fold.

```
onlypos1 = foldr maybekeep []
  where maybekeep x tl | x >= 0    = x : tl
                       | otherwise = tl
```

This operation is known as a `filter`, keeping only some parts:

```
onlypos2 = filter dowekeep
  where dowekeep x = x >= 0
onlypos3 = filter (\x -> x >= 0)
onlypos4 = filter (>= 0)
```

But this is of course only one of many possible approaches. For instance, strictness analysis can lead to the conclusion that `length` is better implemented as `foldl' (\a _ -> succ a) 0` than `foldr (\_ a -> succ a) 0`. Indeed, that is its basic form in the Prelude:

```
length = foldl' (\c _ -> c+1) 0
```

We see that the combining function of `length` ignores the value of one argument, merely requires it to be there. This can naturally be merged with our condition that only some elements count:

```
lengthFilter1 = length . filter
lengthFilter2 pred = foldl' predCount 0
  where predCount c x = if pred x then c+1 else c
countNonNegative = lengthFilter2 nonNegative
  where nonNegative x = x >= 0
```

Incidentally, 0 isn't positive. It's non-negative.

In the end, Haskell's lazy lists mean we can use them to fuse traversals; `length . filter (>=0)` will only read the input list once, because the only reason it's processing results from `filter` is that `length` consumes them. The filtered list never exists as a fully expanded structure, unlike e.g. Python or PHP. This form is likely one of the most readable, but others exist, e.g.:

```
countNonNegatives xs = sum [1 | x <- xs, x >= 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
filtering p cons x r = if | p x -> cons x r | otherwise -> r

countPositives = length 
                   . filter (> 0)
               = foldr (\x r -> r + 1) 0                              -- r++
                   . foldr (filtering (> 0) (:)            ) []
               =     foldr (filtering (> 0) (\x r -> r + 1))  0
```

(since folds *fuse* by composing their reducer transformers, a-la *"fold replaces the cons with a reducer operation, so why create the cons in the first place if it gonna be replaced anyway"*), and

```
filtering (> 0) (\x r -> r + 1) x r 
                     = if | (> 0) x -> (\x r -> r + 1) x r | otherwise -> r
                     = if | x > 0 -> r + 1 | otherwise -> r
```

and thus, a version with *fold* and *increment* that you wanted,

```
countPositives = foldr (\x r -> if | x > 0 -> r + 1 | otherwise -> r) 0  -- r++
```

You can take it from here.