# Using Haskell's foldr

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning Haskell and I've been wrestling with this problem:

> Write `func :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` (take elements of a list until the predicate is false) using `foldr`

This is what I have so far:

```
func :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
func f li = foldr f True li
```

and got the following errors:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Bool’
```

and

```
Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘Bool -> Bool’
Expected type: a -> Bool -> Bool
Actual type: a -> Bool
```

I'm a bit confused since I learned foldr by passing a function with two arguments and getting a single value. For example I've used the function by calling

```
foldr (\x -> \y -> x*y*5) 1 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

to get a single value but not sure how it works when passing a single argument function into foldr and getting a list in return. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: `foldr` has a first parameter a function of tye `a -> Bool -> a`, here you specify that `f` has type `a -> Bool`, so it looks like you want as output `Bool` instead of `[a]`, and as functio `a -> Bool -> Bool`?

Comment: You say "not sure how [foldr] works when passing a single-argument function". The answer to that is easy: it *doesn't* work.

Comment: "*how it works when passing a single argument function into foldr and getting a list in return*" - by not doing that. Your job in this task is to write an appropriate wrapper function that calls `f` and operates with a list.

Comment: see `filtering` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52678045/849891). It is related to your problem. You will need to tweak it. ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034637/849891) is also related). disclaimer: both are my answers.

Comment: a followup question for you: implement `takeUntil p xs` which takes elements `x` from `xs` until the first `p x` returns `True`; including that first successful `x` in the resulting list as its last element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s do an easier case first, and write a function that uses foldr to do nothing (to break down the list and make a the same list). Let’s look at the type signature of `foldr`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
```

And we want to write an expression of the form

```
foldr ?1 ?2 :: [a] -> [a]
```

Now this tells us that (in the signature of `foldr`) we can replace `b` with `[a]`.

A thing we haven’t worked out, `?2`, is what we replace the end of the list with and it has type `b = [a]`. We don’t really have anything of type `a` so let’s just try the most stupid thing we can:

```
foldr ?1 []
```

And now the next missing thing: we have `?1 :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. Let’s write a function for this. Now there are two reasonable things we can do with a list of things and another thing and nothing else:

1. Add it to the start
2. Add it to the end

I think 1 is more reasonable so let’s try that:

```
myFunc = foldr (\x xs -> x : xs) []
```

And now we can try it out:

```
> myFunc [1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

---

So what is the intuition for `foldr` here? Well one way to think of it is that the function passed gets put into your list instead of `:`, with the other item replacing `[]` so we get

```
foldr f x [1,2,3,4]
——>
foldr f x (1:(2:(3:(4:[]))))
——>
f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (f 4 x)))
```

So how can we do what we want (essentially implement `takeWhile` with `foldr`) by choosing our function carefully? Well there are two cases:

1. The predicate is true on the item being considered
2. The predicate is false for the item being considered

In case 1 we need to include our item in the list, and so we can try doing things like we did with our identity function above.

In case 2, we want to not include the item, and not include anything after it, so we can just return `[]`.

Suppose our function does the right thing for the predicate "less than 3", here is how we might evaluate it:

```
f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (f 4 x)))
--T    T    F    F   (Result of predicate)
-- what f should become:
1 : (2 : ([]         ))
——>
[1,2]
```

So all we need to do is implement `f`. Suppose the predicate is called `p`. Then:

```
f x xs = if p x then x : xs else []
```

And now we can write

```
func p = foldr f [] where
  f x xs = if p x then x : xs else []
```

Comment: Thank you Dan! Quick trivial questions: In the result why do you not need to pattern match for [a]? Why do you not pass in the second argument for foldr? By "second argument" I meant the x value in your `foldr f x [1,2,3,4]` example.

Comment: @justan0therlurker I pass `[]` but don’t really mention it. If you get to the end of the list then the result is `[]`. Just ask what `func p []` should be.

Comment: still a bit confused. So when I explicitly pattern match for [a] by doing: `func p as = foldr f [] as ...` it works the same way. How is it able to infer that the [a] parameter will still be passed into foldr when you don't explicitly pattern match for it and feed it into foldr?

Comment: In Haskell there is a feature called partial evaluation. Specifically, the following are equivalent (so long as the types are ok): `\x -> f y x`, and `f y`